# 4 ears, Possible or Inconceivable?

Tags: evolution, creature-design

This question has no background information here. I just want to know if there are any evolutionary advantages for a species to have 4 ears?(The kind a mammal has).

Comment: Yes there is. This answer has no background information :)

Comment: You mean organ used for hearing, a spider's legs contain many hairs which detect vibration in the air to sound out prey, akin to the design of our ear.

Comment: By ear I mean mammal ears

Comment: Depending on their arrangement, you could have a symmetrical head while also being able to pinpoint the exact direction of a sound in both horizontal and vertical planes, much like owls (though they do it with only 2 by having them asymmetrically placed).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Evolution is thrifty.  One of the most effective processes I have seen for determining if evolution might make something happen is to look at what is simpler to do (i.e. can be done with 2 ears), and see if the environment can encourage development of something more complicated.

In the case of ears, I'll look at 2 ears, and what the limits of this approach are.  I could look at 3, which is also simpler than  4 eared creature, but symmetry tends to prefer even numbers, and it turns out that an ear right in the center line isn't too useful.

So what are the limits of 2 ears:

- 3d sound is difficult.  We can easily discern the direction of a sound left to right, because of the travel time of the soundwave to our ears.  For up and down, we actually rely on frequency distributions.  If we know what a sound *should* sound like, such as our own name called by a friend, we can hear the effects of all those little funny shapes in our ear, and our shoulders, and determine by frequencies which direction the sound came from.  With 3 or even 4 ears, more options show up.  In fact, with 4 ears, you have enough information to not only get a direction but a distance, just from the time delays (we use that effect in GPS!)
- Redundancy.  2 is the bare minimum number of ears for our particular environment.  If one gets damaged, we become weak on that side.
- Alternate frequencies.  While nature *vastly* prefers having one auditory organ over two for simplicity reasons, if we had a reason to listen to two different sets of frequencies, it might make sense to have two fundamentally different kinds of ears.
- Alternate synergy.  Perhaps we get a freak mutation that gives us 4 ears, but we find that having 4 earlobes is is useful (maybe having more space for earrings is a sexually selected trait).  Evolution is not embarrassed by anything.  If it's useful, it's kept!

I'm sure there's others, but that might be enough to get your creative juices flowing.

Comment: Dang, I was just writing about the 3D localization. It's one of those interesting things about hearing that people often forget to think about. +1 (in a few minutes when my vote count is reset :) ).

Comment: I ran an awesome experiment a while back.  I grabbed a pair of spoons so that I could click them together, and got a friend to sit down and close their eyes.  I then had them reach out in the direction they thought the click was coming from, and clicked the spoon a few times.  Every time, they got the left-to-right axis perfect, but their up and down was wrong.  Then I let them open their eyes, and observe a few clicks.  Then I had them close their eyes and do the experiment over again.  This time, they reached for the spoon dead-on, every time.

Comment: Literally they were able to use the visual information from seeing the spoons click to determine the real direction they were in, and then back out whatever transform their ears did, to hear the undistorted *true* sound of the clicking.  Then, when they heard it again, they could use the frequency distributions to get the location right.  I think it is fair to say that they actually heard with their eyes, and it is the coolest example of sensory fusion I have seen (or heard).

Comment: @Samuel (should have linked the above comments to you)

Comment: Very cool. It's an interesting problem for video game and virtual reality designers too. It also raises interesting metrics for use in the design of cochlear implants and hearing aids. Not only is captured tone important (especially in tonal languages) but the phase information also need to be preserved (and likely recorded in ear).

Comment: Just a small note to add: when we can't tell which direction a sound is coming from we often tilt our heads to place the sound on one side to figure it out. If an organism couldn't perform this maneuver easily for any reason (maybe it's a plant or just holding still) then it would require 4 ears, ideally in a tetrahedron-like configuration, to locate the sound precisely.

Comment: @MikeNichols Good point.  Also, we'd never know when that creature is confused, because it wouldn't develop the instinct to cock its head to one side when confused!

Comment: Random fact: the praying mantis has just a single ear, located on the underside of its belly, just forward of its hind legs. This ear is tuned to detect ultrasound, produced by echo-locating bats. Studies have shown that praying mantids are quite good at evading bats. Perhaps not all the ears need to be used in normal ways?  Maybe one pair is a different frequency band?

Answer (score 0):

Before an animal can have 4 ears, it needs 4 structures with the right structure for an ear to evolve from. This is a problem, as tetrapods simply do not have enough holes with the right structure and place to become ears. However, a four-eared creature could evolve from a bichir-like creature with tetrapod like nostrils, with the ears being modified spiracles and gill-slits

Comment: Not really, depending on exactly what is meant by "ears".  In the broadest sense of sound detecting senses, fish have the lateral line system in addition to more mammalian-style ears: https://dosits.org/animals/sound-reception/how-do-fish-hear/

Comment: @jamesqf What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that fish have lateral line organs, which are quite similar to ears, both in function and in the anatomy of the receptors.  So fish effectively have either 4 ears, or a multitude, because the many individual sensors in the lateral line are similar to ears: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_line#Anatomy

Comment: @jamesqf I was saying that a bichir had enough holes with the right structures around them for 4 mammalian ears to evolve